# How to add only right border to UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, border

I want to add a white border to an UIImageView. I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imagePath];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    CGRect rect = imageView.frame;        
    rect.size.width = rect.size.width + 1; // create white right border
    [imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; 

    imageView.frame = rect;
    [myViewView addSubview:imageView];
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I now did it like

```
        CALayer *sublayer = [CALayer layer];
        sublayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
        sublayer.frame = CGRectMake(imageView.bounds.size.width, 0, 1, imageView.frame.size.height);
        [imageView.layer addSublayer:sublayer];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a UIView that is larger than the UIImage view, and set the image view's frame to be 0,0, width+1, height, and that will add the extra to the side.

Comment: you make a regular UIView, and then add in the imageView. The UIView should be the one that is larger, not the imageView.

Comment: but the UIImageView is inherited from an UIView. Isn't that just one view to much then? why is my code not working?

Comment: In your answer, don't you mean to say, "set the UIView's frame to be ..."?  As it stands you say to make the image view larger, not the view behind it.